# Complexity function

Tags: function, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

could you help me to determine whether the following function of complexity:

f(n)=5n^3+1800nlogn+18

is of order O(n^2), O(n^4), OMEGA(n^3),OMEGA(n^5),TETA(n^3),TETA(n^5)

I think it is O(n^4), TETA(n^3) is right?
I arrived at this solution because I calculated the limit n-> inf f (n) / g (n) in the various orders!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually `O(n^3)`: n^3 being the highest power in your function.

(and `nlogn` < `n^2` < `n^3`, and `18` being a constant)

Comment: I actually only these choices O(n^2), O(n^4), OMEGA(n^3),OMEGA(n^5),TETA(n^3),TETA(n^5)

Comment: So it is both O(n^4), TETA(n^3), OMEGA(n^3).